# OpenGL + GLEW + MinGW application linking issue

Tags: windows, opengl, mingw, eclipse-cdt, glew

I'm getting some undefined references when building my project. Here's the build log:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project test ****

**** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o src\main.o ..\src\main.cpp
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o src\test.o ..\src\test.cpp
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o src\window.o ..\src\window.cpp
..\src\window.cpp: In member function 'void Window::StartRenderContext()':
..\src\window.cpp:150:24: warning: NULL used in arithmetic
..\src\window.cpp:161:28: warning: NULL used in arithmetic
..\src\window.cpp:174:24: warning: NULL used in arithmetic
g++ -mwindows -l glew32 -l glew32s -l glu32 -l opengl32 -o test.exe src\window.o src\test.o src\main.o
src\window.o: In function `ZN6Window18StartRenderContextEv':
C:\eclipse\workspace\test\Debug/../src/window.cpp:101: undefined reference to `wglCreateContext@4'
C:\eclipse\workspace\test\Debug/../src/window.cpp:102: undefined reference to `wglMakeCurrent@8'
C:\eclipse\workspace\test\Debug/../src/window.cpp:115: undefined reference to `glewInit'
C:\eclipse\workspace\test\Debug/../src/window.cpp:125: undefined reference to `wglMakeCurrent@8'
C:\eclipse\workspace\test\Debug/../src/window.cpp:126: undefined reference to `wglDeleteContext@4'
C:\eclipse\workspace\test\Debug/../src/window.cpp:148: undefined reference to `__wglewChoosePixelFormatARB'
C:\eclipse\workspace\test\Debug/../src/window.cpp:159: undefined reference to `__wglewChoosePixelFormatARB'
C:\eclipse\workspace\test\Debug/../src/window.cpp:185: undefined reference to `__wglewCreateContextAttribsARB'
C:\eclipse\workspace\test\Debug/../src/window.cpp:194: undefined reference to `__wglewCreateContextAttribsARB'
C:\eclipse\workspace\test\Debug/../src/window.cpp:204: undefined reference to `__wglewCreateContextAttribsARB'
C:\eclipse\workspace\test\Debug/../src/window.cpp:214: undefined reference to `__wglewCreateContextAttribsARB'
C:\eclipse\workspace\test\Debug/../src/window.cpp:227: undefined reference to `wglMakeCurrent@8'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Build error occurred, build is stopped
Time consumed: 8128  ms.
```

Here's my link command:

```
g++ -mwindows -l glew32 -l glew32s -l glu32 -l opengl32 -o test.exe src\window.o src\test.o src\main.o
```

Is this correct? I'm using the 64-bit binaries of glew (I think the 32s don't mean anything). Were they only meant to be used with visual studio?

Here's the includes in my code:

```
#include "Windows.h"
#include "GL/glew.h"
#include "GL/wglew.h"
#include "GL/gl.h"
#include "GL/glu.h"
#include "test.h"
```

I am using Eclipse Indigo CDT, MinGW, Win32, OpenGL, and glew.

Comment: Why are you including `wglew.h`?  And why are you including `gl.h` after including `glew.h`?

Comment: I'm using wglew for initializing glew with wgl, which I believe is the exclusive library required for that. In terms of gl and glu I included them in the hopes that it would resolve the function calls. It didn't, so I might try removing them. I'll remove wglew as well and see if that might actually resolve these issues, I'm not sure though.

Comment: Alright, I've narrowed down the includes to just `glew.h` and `wglew.h`, I am also now only including `glew32s.lib`, and have defined `GLEW_STATIC` yet I'm still getting the exact same undefined references! If somebody tries a glew application in an Eclipse Indigo CDT environment with MinGW, could they post their results please? xD

Comment: I solved it! I just decided that the precompiled binaries they had up in sourceforge were ONLY for visual studio, so I downloaded the source and built it for MinGW, now it works!! Ah, the things we learn when installing 3rd party libraries... I will post the answer after the 8-hour time limit.

Comment: So @AutoBotAM... the answer? xD

Answer (score 1):

I solved "glew undefined reference" problems.

My development environment is eclipse CDT with MinGW on Windows 7 (x64).

The solution is the following 3 steps:

1. Add source code: `#define GLEW_STATIC`
2. Add linker flag: `-lglew32s -lopengl32 -lfreeglut`
3. Add compiling flag: `gcc -DGLEW_STATIC`

If needed, you have to add `-lglu32 -glut32` etc.